# React: useState value doesn't update on parameter value change

Tags: reactjs, use-state

In the example below, the value of the `display` state on Child component never updates, even if the `show` parameter toggles between true and false.

I expect it to receive the value and to update accordingly. Can someone please elaborate on why this is not working?

(I know I can use a useEffect callback and setDisplay(show) from inside it, but I'd like to know why a simpler approach like this doesn't work)

```
function Child({ show }) {
  const [display] = React.useState(show);

  console.log({ show, display });
  return display ? "Message!" : null;
}

function Parent() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
      <Child show={show} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-boilerplate-4hexp?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Well the value of display is set only on the first render of the component (because it is state and state doesnt change with renders, but only when you tell it to change). If you want it to be changing with changing props  just use a normal constant instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the `useState` in the Child component is reading `show` when it first loads but then never updates because it's just set, it doesn't automatically update.

You could either just use `show` directly which should be used for `return show ? 'message' : <></>`

Or you could still use the local state with `useState`, but you would need to add a `useEffect` to listen to the props change then change the local state of that child.

**Update:**

Third option for your current code to work would also be to do:

```
{show && <Child show={show} />}
```

That way at the time when it's true, the component will read the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

`display` is local component state of `Child`, given an initial value from `props.show` when `Child` mounted. There is never a state update within `Child` to render any other value of `display`. This is *actually* an anti-pattern to store passed props in local component state, but there are two alternatives/solutions to getting `display` to update.

Use an effect to update state when the props update

```
function Child({ show }) {
  const [display, setDisplay] = React.useState(show);
  useEffect(() => setDisplay(show), [show]);

  console.log(show, display);
  return display ? "Message!" : null;
}
```

Or better, just consume the prop `show` directly

```
function Child({ show }) {
  console.log(show);
  return show ? "Message!" : null;
}
```

The benefit of the latter is that the new value of `show` ***and*** the updated/rerendered UI occur in the same render cycle. With the former (the anti-pattern) the state needs to update *then* the component rerenders, so the updated UI is a render cycle delayed.